# Automatic Background Processes

Tags: shell, ssh, raspberry-pi, background-process, nohup

I'm running my Raspberry Pi off an SSH server, and want to be able to access it out of home. Sure, all I need is an IP. But with my terrible internet, it's constantly dropping out. My IP is constantly changing.

To counteract this, I setup a script to test if my IP is the same as it was 30 minutes ago, every 30 minutes. I also have a script set to kill this, so it doesn't go on forever or until reboot.

**How can I make my process run itself in the background, without user interaction via. regex like `nohup`? Can `nohup` be self-automated? I want this functionality so I don't need an extra computer open while away. (Again, I'm accessing my Pi from SSH)**

Comment: I am not sure if Pi support `crond` or not. But I hope you can install and manage it.

Comment: @pmverma Just checked, not installed. Should I just `apt-get`? How would I use it?

Comment: @pmverma I do have `cron`.

Comment: Well you can run your script every 30 minutes background process.

Comment: @pmverma I'm sorry? What? I use `cron` every 30 minutes yes, but not in the background... I don't understand what your saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following to run command in background, it detaches from terminal

```
nohup command &
```

or if running command from termial, to put in background do:

```
command
```

then `ctrl+z` on keyboard to suspend current process, then type:

```
bg
```

to push suspended process to background. type:

```
jobs
```

to list current jobs, including your background process. type:

```
fg %n
```

where `n` in job number from `jobs` command.

`nohup command &` can easily be scripted.

Comment: Firstly, `nohup command &` gave me an error. I can give it to you if you want. Secondly, how would I execute CTRL+Z in a script?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the script in use?

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed `crontab`
then type command `crontab -e`
And write following

`30 * * * * /home/user/ipcheck.sh`

This will run `ipcheck.sh` every 30 minute in background.